# Symfony 3 Ajax login always returns "Bad Credentials"

Tags: php, ajax, authentication, symfony, symfony-forms

I've been working in a web and a few weeks ago I implement an ajax login (from here http://www.webtipblog.com/adding-an-ajax-login-form-to-a-symfony-project/) and everything works until I deploy the project in production.

Today, testing new functionalities, I can't login in production, but neither in local enviorement. Of course, I change something but I can't detect the error.

WHen I try to login (I create new users for this and also try with old ones), the controller always returns me "Bad credentials" error.

Service.yml

```
acme.security.authentication_handler:
    class: AppBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler
    public: false
    arguments: ["@router", "@session"]
```

Security.yml

```
providers:
    our_db_provider_front:
        entity:
            class: Corpora360EntityBundle:User 

firewalls:
    front:
        anonymous: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
        pattern:    ^/
        http_basic: ~
        provider: our_db_provider_front
        # e
        form_login:
            check_path:      ajaxLogin
            success_handler: acme.security.authentication_handler
            failure_handler: acme.security.authentication_handler
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager            
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
encoders:
    Corpora360\EntityBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12
```

AuthentificationHandler.php

```
private $router;
private $session;

/**
* Constructor
*
* @author   Joe Sexton <joe@webtipblog.com>
* @param    RouterInterface $router
* @param    Session $session
*/
public function __construct( RouterInterface $router, Session $session )
{
    $this->router  = $router;
    $this->session = $session;
}

/**
* onAuthenticationSuccess
*
* @author   Joe Sexton <joe@webtipblog.com>
* @param    Request $request
* @param    TokenInterface $token
* @return   Response
*/
public function onAuthenticationSuccess( Request $request, TokenInterface $token )
{
    // if AJAX login
    if ( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ) {

        $array = array( 'success' => true ); // data to return via JSON
        $response = new Response( json_encode( $array ) );
        $response->headers->set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );

        return $response;

    // if form login
    } else {

        if ( $this->session->get('_security.main.target_path' ) ) {

            $url = $this->session->get( '_security.main.target_path' );

        } else {

            $url = $this->router->generate( 'home_page' );

        } // end if

        return new RedirectResponse( $url );

    }
}

/**
* onAuthenticationFailure
*
* @author   Joe Sexton <joe@webtipblog.com>
* @param    Request $request
* @param    AuthenticationException $exception
* @return   Response
*/
public function onAuthenticationFailure( Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception )
{
    // if AJAX login
    if ( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ) {

        $array = array( 'success' => false, 'message' => $exception->getMessage() ); // data to return via JSON
        $response = new Response( json_encode( $array ) );
        $response->headers->set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );

        return $response;

    // if form login
    } else {

        // set authentication exception to session
        $request->getSession()->set(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);

        return new RedirectResponse( $this->router->generate( 'login_route' ) );
    }
}
```

}

UserController.php

```
/**
 * @Route("/acceder-ajax", name="ajaxLogin")
 */
public function loginAjaxAction(Request $request){

        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        return new Response(true);

}

/**
 * @Route("/registro", name="register")
 */
public function registerAction(Request $request){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $data = $request->request->all();

    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query
        ->select('u')
        ->from('Corpora360EntityBundle:User', 'u')
        ->where('u.email = :email')
        ->andWhere('u.password IS NOT NULL')
        ->setParameter(':email', $data['email']);

    $userExist = $query->getQuery()->getResult();

    if (count($userExist) > 0){
        return $this->get('response')->swalResponse("error", "", "Ya existe un usuario con ese email");
    }else {

        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $query
            ->select('u')
            ->from('Corpora360EntityBundle:User', 'u')
            ->where('u.email = :email')
            ->andWhere('u.password IS NULL')
            ->setParameter(':email', $data['email']);

        $userApp = $em->getRepository('Corpora360EntityBundle:User')->findBy(array(
            "email" => $data['email'],
            "password" => NULL
        ));

        //$userApp = $query->getQuery()->getResult();

        if (count($userApp) > 0){
            $userApp = $userApp[0];
            $passwordPlain = substr(uniqid(),0,7);
            $userApp->setPlainPassword($passwordPlain);

            $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')->encodePassword($userApp, $userApp->getPlainPassword());
            $userApp->setPassword($password);

            return $this->get('response')->swalResponse("success", "", "Ya tenemos tu email registrado desde la app. Por favor, revisa tu email con tu contraseña para la web");

        }else {
            // 1) build the form
            $user = new User();

            $user->setPlainPassword($data['password']);
            $user->setEmail($data['email']);
            // 3) Encode the password (you could also do this via Doctrine listener)
            $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
                ->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);

            // 4) save the User!
            try {
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();
            } catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->resetManager();
                return $this->get('response')->swalResponse("error", "", "Ya existe un usuario con ese email");

            } catch (NotNullConstraintViolationException $e) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->resetManager();
                return $this->get('response')->swalResponse("error", "", "Se ha producido un error al registrarte. Por favor, comprueba los datos y vuelve a intentarlo");

            }
            return $this->get('response')->swalResponse("success", "", "Bienvenido. Ya puedes acceder con tu cuenta");
        }
    }

}
```

The password field in database is VARCHAR(255) and I check the POST params going to "ajaxLogin" and are "_username", "_password", "_remenber_me", _csrf_token" an "_target_path" with the correct values.

Please I need a little help here. And sorry for my poor english...